# World map in SharePoint page without an Internet connection?

Tags: dictionary, sharepoint-2010

I have to pin my organization branch location on the map so that I need a map. But my server don't have an Internet connection to get the map from Google or Bing. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few products out there to integrate maps into SharePoint:

- [Virtual Map View Web Part](http://store.bamboosolutions.com/pc-51-1-virtual-map-view-web-part-release-16.aspx?gclid=CITIkoW5oKUCFU0_4wodiy73Jg)
- [Free Google Map Chart Sharepoint Web Part](http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5748)

Personally, I haven't tried any. Nonetheless, giving there is no Internet connection, you have to use a third-party solution.